# WebScriptServiceHostFactory wcf service in IIS 6

Tags: wcf, iis-6

I am implementing wcf service using the config-less available with **WebScriptServiceHostFactory** in dotNet 4. On my local development server the web service returns appropriate content in the response body. I tested the same on my local machine IIS 7 and it works great.

But, now I have moved the service on **IIS 6 with SSL** enabled. The service when invoked calls the web-method as usual, with no server exceptions. The response body is missing its contents. 
The web-service is of the following format:
https:///qa/AjaxService.svc/MyMethod

I have verified the following:
1. Wild-card mapping set to aspnet_isapi.dll [Check file exists - unchecked]
2. Anonymous Authentication enabled

I would appreciated some input, if some has already experienced such a weird behavior.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I resolved my issue by using **WebServiceHostFactory** instead. I still don't know what caused issues with **WebScriptServiceHostFactory** on IIS 6 and .NET 4.0.

I am still looking for any input/resolution with *"**WebScriptServiceHostFactory** on IIS 6 and .NET 4.0"*